# Null object pattern for functional paradigm

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, null-object-pattern

Using Typescript for an Angular ngrx application, i have to do a lot of checks wether a value i access or get passed is null/undefined, eg calling .map() on a list that might exist.

What is the way to go? Ensure that the entire Codebase nevererver hands over a null? Check before every call and in case generate null-obects like empty lists? Or is there some kind of null-object like pattern for functional programming?

@Comment by Pavel:
We have a list of items that can be selected and if so, details are expanded in the view. It happened to me that when deleting an opened item in the list, the application crashed, because the reference to the opened item was set to null. I fixed this by making a null check on all selectors i wrote to fix the app from crashing, as i had seen with many other selectors, who work with the applications local state in the browser.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: for list it's good practice to return empty instead of null. For other type try not to use null and use undefined instead. Just avoid using it for validity. You could enable --strictNullChecks (only if angular >= 5).

Comment: @JEY i thought about "just don't use null - so no need for defensive programming. But i doubt i can ensure this, since angular and async. And as much as i like the idea of fail fast to find the bug, i would prefer my app to not crash. Will take a look at strictNullChecks

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of well-known patterns that can help here.

### The Option Type, aka Maybe

Maybe/Option is a sum type that has the following structure in TypeScript:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | void;
```

You can read more about implementing it in the [typescript user manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html), just `ctrl-f` for 'maybe' since they seem to eschew fragment identifiers for some reason.

### Decorators

The problem with Maybe (one of them anyways) is that it quickly becomes *viral*, it takes over your entire codebase and every value becomes a Maybe. Dealing with this is especially annoying without pattern-matching (the examples in the typescript manual are quite verbose). A better option IMHO, since JavaScript/TypeScript lack any sort of existential operator is to write your functions with no null checks, and then decorate them with functions that do the checking.

```
function argCheckDecorator(f) {
  return function(...args) {
    // Functions have a length property that is their arity.
    // You could modify this to only check the first argument,
    // not check arity for varargs, etc.
    if (
      args.length === f.length &&
      args.every(arg => arg !== null && arg !== undefined)
    ) {
      return f.apply(this, args);
    } else {
      // optionally warn console
      // console.warn(`Called ${f.name} with invalid arguments ${args}.`);
      return null;
    }
  }
}https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries
```

The obvious problem here is that you're doing rather extensive run-time checking (which AFAIK is what led you to ask the question in the first place) rather than leaning on the compiler. Unfortunately in JavaScript/TypeScript your options are always going to be limited, there's no way to guarantee that a call to the DOM will never return `null` or that an object property access will never returned `undefined` (at least if you're parsing, say, a JSON HTTP response into an object).

At least with the function decorator you move the null-checking out of every single function. Turning my higher-order function into a TypeScript decorator is left as an exercise to the reader.

### Update

Just to give an example of what I'm talking about in the comments:

```
// messy-shell.js
// All DOM mutation, AJAX calls, optional params, null checks, etc.
// go here.
import * as ideal from './perfect-world.js';
const getDOMElement = (selector, element=document) => {
  return (selector && element instanceof HTMLElement) ?
    ideal.getDOMElement(selector, element) : null;
};

const getAJAXData => (url, method='GET', params) => {
  let p = params ? // IRL you'll want to do more checking than this
    fetch(url, { body: params, method }) :
    fetch(url, { method });

  return p.then(resp => {
    if (resp.statusCode >= 200 && resp.statusCode < 400) {
      return resp.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error(`${resp.statusCode} response.`);
    }
  }).then(data => {
    if (data && (data.length || Object.keys(data).length)) {
      return ideal.processAJAXData(data);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Empty data response.');
    }
  }).then(processedData => {
    // update DOM here, or skip this and just return Promise<processedData>
  }).catch(err => {
    // do error handling
  });
};
```

Meanwhile, back at the ranch...

```
// perfect-world.js
// Assumes that no args are ever omitted, nothing ever
// throws (catching is up to the caller). Functions in this
// file may also call each other, but with caution. Any function
// that uses the result of something that might fail go in messy-shell.
// Functional, in the Functional Programming sense.
export const getDOMElement = (selector, element) => {
  return element.querySelector(selector);
};

// NOTE: knows nothing of Promises, try/catch, JSON.parse, etc.
// Doesn't mutate the DOM either, just processes server response.
export const processAJAXData = data => {
  return Object.entries(data).forEach(datum => {
    // do stuff.
  });
};
```

Now you won't necessarily want this level of ceremony for every little function, but if your team/codebase/problem domain is big enough you might. Some nice properties fall out of this:

1. The stuff in the ideal world is easily tested.
2. The stuff in the ideal world can be easily statically analyzed.
3. The stuff in the ideal world is uncluttered and largely self-documenting

You may want to check [this](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) out as well.

Comment: About the "no way to guarantee that a call to the DOM will never return null". I thought about this myself and in terms of the code i actually work with this is true, but is it realy impossible to reach a null-free/clean state? Obvious answer: Impossible cause Angular/Async. Using ngrx, is it posible for the state and everything browser local to stay clean?

Comment: @Lex Has nothing to do with Angular or any other part of your chosen stack per se, it's inherent in the nature of web programming (and programming in general for that matter). The idea behind encoding the absence of value in the type system (e.g. with Maybe) is not to eliminate it, but rather to catch any cases where the programmer doesn't explicitly deal with the possibility. One functional approach (and the one I'd recommend) is to write the core of your program, as much as possible, to live in a perfect world with a thin shell that interfaces with the messy real world and calls down into

Comment: the pure core as needed. Either way, no type system will likely ever be able to, say, ensure an HTTP request never fails.